# Совмещение lock и параллельного прохода данного блока

Tags: c#, многопоточность, lock

Есть цикл, в котором рассчитываются данные. В каждом новом проходе создается объект с входными параметрами и после расчета эти входных параметров выдается конечное число - результат. Т.к. итерации не зависят друг от друга, через `AsParallel` я добавил параллельное выполнение данного цикла. Но, у меня каждый поток пересекается с другим. Окей. Я добавил в функции расчета lock. Но тут появилась проблема, что расчеты не будут вестись параллельно, потому что к новому расчету нельзя будет приступить, пока предыдущий поток не закончится. И задача в том, чтобы сделать проход по циклу параллельным, но, чтобы каждый поток никак не залезал в данные другого потока. Как можно решить такую задачу?
Например :

```
public class A
{
    public int g;
    public int c;

    public A(int gC, int cC)
    {
        g = gC;
        c = cC;
    }

}


public class C
{
    public C()
    {

    }

    public double Result()
    {
        double g = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
            {
                double resCalc = Calculation(i, j);
                if (resCalc > g)
                    g = resCalc;
            }
        }
        return g;
    }

    public double Calculation(int Ag, int Ac)
    {
        A a = new A(Ag, Ac);
        return a.c + a.g;
    }
}
```

Пример написан на скорую руку, но результат примерно такой. Здесь мы в классе `C` создаем объект класса `A` с данными параметрами цикла, и считаем сумму параметров. Т.к. каждая итерация не зависит от предыдущей, мы можем это сделать параллельным, но тогда потоки будут пересекаться. Нужно, чтобы каждый поток создавал объект класса `A` и работал именно с ним и возвращал значение именно своё. Если я добавляю lock, то у меня убирается многопоточность цикла, потому что расчет идет последовательно.

Comment: Чтобы вам ответили приведите минимальный самодостаточный пример

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "потоки будут пересекаться"?

Comment: @PavelMayorov то, что если параллельно потоки будут вычислять созданный каждым объект A, то в данные расчета одного потока может параллельно влезть другой поток, который изменяет эти же данные.
Также по-другому описано на одном сайте
`Здесь у нас запускаются пять потоков, которые работают с общей переменной x. И мы предполагаем, что метод выведет все значения x от 1 до 8. И так для каждого потока. Однако в реальности в процессе работы будет происходить переключение между потоками, и значение переменной x становится непредсказуемым.`

Comment: @Fresto каким образом поток влезет в чужие данные если у каждого есть своя копия?

Comment: @PavelMayorov вот это я и пытаюсь узнать, потому что, у меня в коде входными данными являются 2 параметра int, как и в кратком примере. На выходе получается результат всех расчетов. Если я узнаю, при каких именно параметрах получается максимальных расчет и прогоню использую только эти параметры, без цикла, без параллельного вычисления, то результат получится другой. Поэтому я и пытаюсь понять, как это возможно.

Comment: @Fresto блин, ну так если у вас ошибка в коде - то и спрашивайте про ошибку! Зачем вы ерунду какую-то про параллельный лок сочиняете?

Comment: @Fresto приведите тот код, который выполняется с ошибкой. Желательно выкинув из него все лишнее, это называется [mcve]

Comment: @PavelMayorov Так я говорю про то, что один и тот же код, в параллельной реализации дает один результат, а в одиночной другой.

Comment: @Fresto я не вижу у вас параллельной реализации. Очевидно, ошибка именно в ней.

Comment: @PavelMayorov хорошо, попробую написать код, близкий по смыслу с моим проектом.

Comment: @PavelMayorov код слишком обширный в итоге. Но, если вы сказали, что параллельные потоки не могут пересекаться, если имеют свои копии объектов, то возможно ошибка в чем-то другом. Буду уже искать сам. Спасибо за ответы.

Comment: @PavelMayorov возможно ошибка в том еще, что у меня данные у каждого потока берутся из кэша и тут возможно какой-то разлад.

Comment: @PavelMayorov и всё же ошибка возможно в другом, но чтобы не добавлять сюда целый проект, я могу вам его показать в skype и вы объясните, в чем может быть проблема? Я думаю, максимум пару минут займет поиск проблемы. 
Skype - fr3sto (на аватаре черный глаз)